# How do I print something after n seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if this is a basic question but I'm just trying to print a string after a certain number of seconds and I'm not sure how to do it. I can put an input beforehand so that there is a reference for when the start of the 6 seconds.

something like this:

```
x = input()
after 6 seconds:
    print('Hello World!')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `import time`

```
import time

x = input()
time.sleep(6)
print('Hello World!')
```